# How to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 and enable only 1.2 in Apache 2.4.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2k fips, RHEL 7

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache2.4

I tried to enable TLS 1.2 in `/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` in Apache 2.4.10 as below combinations.

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

After restarting the `httpd` service, I am getting the error `illegal Protocol TLSv1.2` as below:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 260 of /opt/NSAx/apache2.4-npservers/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'
```

Then I updated `SSLProtocol` in `http-ssl.conf` file:

```
SSLProtocol -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
```

After restarting the `httpd` service, I am getting the error `illegal Protocol TLSv1.1` as below:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 260 of /opt/NSAx/apache2.4-npservers/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1'
```

I set the `SSLHonorCipherOrder` in the `httpd-ssl.conf` file both to `on` and `off`.  Still the same error.

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
```

I also tried a different set of `SSLCipersuite` from [this link](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=apache&version=2.4.10&config=intermediate&openssl=1.0.2k-fips&guideline=5.6).

I ran the command `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 hostname` in linux and it returned SSLv3, TLSv1.0 enabled.

Hope, mentioned version of OpenSSL, Apache & Linux OS will support TLS 1.2.

Please help me.  Why does this configuration cause a `illegal protocol` error and how can I enable TLS 1.2 only with this setup?  Really appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Just an fyi dude, this is the "Ask Ubuntu" website.